# What kind of WiFi chip does the xd-705f has?

Tags: tablet, wifi-driver

I'm trying to find the Wifi driver for the [XD-705F Tablet PC](http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/jennyxundu/product-detailnBLETxVZIYWr/China-Tablet-PC-XD-705F-.html).

All the specs I find on-line only say that it supports IEEE 802.11/b/g wireless internet - no specific information regarding the vendor.

Where can I find the driver?

Comment: There are only a couple vendors that actually make the chips.  The standard device driver detected by the OS should be good enough.

Comment: I tried to replace to ROM and now it doesn't recognize the driver. does anybody know where I can find out the specific vendor, so I can get a driver from them?

Comment: look in device manager and find out the vendor ids.

Answer (score 0):

I had good results finding drivers by using the following method:

Look in device manager for the device, go to Properties, Details, then go to Hardware IDs. In that description you will often find a VID (Vendor ID) and a PID (Product ID).
Then you can search for these values to find out what vendor it is, then again search for drivers from that vendor.

For e.g. USB devices you'll often end up finding the info in [Stephen J. Gowdy's list](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids), I don't know how that is for other device types.

This does not work with all hardware, your mileage may vary.